# How to add confirm modal to axios delete

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Before I had this in my row

```
                button(@click="deleteTodo(todo.id)") Delete
```

Now i changed the @click to open modal, but whenever I set on modal confirmation button`@deleteTodo(todo.id)` it gives me error in console Id undefinded. How do I pass the Id to modal from the row im deleting?

Comment: It depends how you call the modal, is it a separate component or in the same template? You need to post your code for anyone to help.

Comment: It's too long code to post, its basically bootstrap modal component, in the same template.
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">` whenever the modal opens, I have Confirm button there with `@click="deleteTodo(todo.id)" but it says it's undefined because it's in a modal.

Comment: Then reduce your code to show a minimal reproducible example. Or even better create an example on Codepen or CodeSandbox or jsFiddle. Clearly `todo` object is not in scope of where your modal code is defined, but without showing us a minimal example it's just guessing...

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, in your data create variable e.g

```
data() {
 return {
   showModalConfirm: false,
   selectedTodo: null,
 }  
}
```

and when you click modal confirm @click="showModalConfirm(todo)", set in your method func like this

```
showModalConfirm(todo) {
 this.showModalConfirm = true;
 this.selectedTodo = todo;
}
```

and now you can get your selected todo data to delete